# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserType is not mapped [from UserType]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The exception is about table not mapping to class, however I failed to debug what went wrong.

I have checked the xml configurations. the class is UserType and the database table is called UserType as well.

**UserType.java**:

```
package com.howtodoinjava.entity;

public class UserType {

private int _userTypeID;
private String _userTypeName;
private boolean _typeIsSuperUser;

public int getUserTypeID() { return _userTypeID; }
public String getUserTypeName() {return _userTypeName; }
public boolean getTypeIsSuperUser() {return _typeIsSuperUser; }

public UserType setUserTypeID(int id) { _userTypeID = id; return this; }
public UserType setUserTypeName(String name) { _userTypeName = name; return this; }
public UserType setTypeIsSuperUser(boolean isSuperUser) { _typeIsSuperUser = isSuperUser; return this; }

}
```

**UserTypeDAOImpl.java**:

```
package com.howtodoinjava.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.howtodoinjava.entity.UserType;

@Repository
public class UserTypeDAOImpl implements UserTypeDAO  {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void add(UserType ut) {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(ut);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserType> getAll() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from UserType").list();
}

public void delete(Integer id) {
    UserType ut= (UserType) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            UserType.class, id);
    if (null != ut) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(ut);
    }
}
}
```

**EditUserTypeController.java**:

```
@Controller
public class EditUserTypeController{

@Autowired
private UserTypeManager userTypeManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(ModelMap map) 
{
    map.addAttribute("UserType", new UserType());
    map.addAttribute("UserTypeList", userTypeManager.getAll());

    return "editEUserTypeList";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserType(@ModelAttribute(value="ut") UserType ut, BindingResult result) 
{
    userTypeManager.add(ut);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String deleteUserType(@PathVariable("id") Integer id)
{
    userTypeManager.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/";
}

public void setUserTypeManager(UserTypeManager new_utm) {
    this.userTypeManager = new_utm;
}
```

}

my **UserType-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.controller" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="UserTypeDAO" class="com.howtodoinjava.dao.UserTypeDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="UserTypeManager" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.UserTypeManagerImpl">    </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping resource="UserType.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**UserType.hbm.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.howtodoinjava.entity.UserType" table="UserType">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            user type
        </meta>
        <id name="_userTypeID" column="UserTypeId" type="int"> <generator class="native"/> </id>         
        <property name="_userTypeName" column="UserTypeName" type="string"/>
        <property name="_typeIsSuperUser" column="TypeIsSuperUser" type="string"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I appreciate any helps!

Comment: Can you add the full error stack trace here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is related to the HQL issue: instead of using from UserType, use from com.howtodojava.entity.UserType;

and the error message will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in hibernate mapping configuration:

- *name*: should be same as class field name and
- *column*: is the name of database table column, or the column name to be set while table creation by hibernate.

Note: The mapping file instructs Hibernate how to map the defined class to the database table.

your UserType.hbm.xml should be look like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.howtodoinjava.entity.UserType" table="UserType">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            user type
        </meta>

        <id name="_userTypeID" column="userTypeID" type="int"> 
           <generator class="native"/>
        </id>         
        <property name="_userTypeName" column="userTypeName" type="string"/>
        <property name="_typeIsSuperUser" column="typeIsSuperUser" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: After fixing that and the userType.hbm.xml, I still get the same error though.. I've edited the codes so that it contains the updated usertype.hbm.xml as well.

Comment: @jl123 It seems somehow `hibernate` is not able to load your 'UserType.hbm.xml' file.
Please post the complete stack trace

Comment: @ankur-singhal thanks for replying. Please see the accepted answer.